# What does it mean to say that the Laplacian commutes with translations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, linear-transformations, laplacian

[image]

In this explanation, $L$ is an operator that could be the Laplacian. However, I don't know what is $f$ and $T$. It later suggests that $T$ is a rotation, **but what is $f$ and why does the relation $L(f\circ T) = (Lf)\circ T$ looks like associativity, not commutativity?**

Comment: It means that if you transate the arguments of a function, and then perform the Laplacian, it is the same as applying the Laplacian to the function first, and then translating the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where it says “for any translation (rotation) on $\mathbb R^n$”, $T$ is that translation or rotation, so $T$ stands for translation and rotation operators. $f$ stands for a function.

That the equation looks more like associativity than like commutativity is due to the somewhat unhelpful notation that they're using. The operator $L$ is being applied from the left and without a symbol, and the translation / rotation operator $T$ is being applied from the right and with the symbol $\circ$. If we use the same notation for these operators, the equation becomes

$$
L(Tf)=T(Lf)\;,
$$

and if we now define the product $AB$ of operators $A$ and $B$ via $(AB)f=A(Bf)$, then this becomes

$$
(LT)f=(TL)f
$$

and thus

$$
LT=TL
$$

(since $f$ is arbitrary, so the equality for all $f$ implies the equality of the operators).

Thus, that $L$ commutes with translations means that it doesn't matter whether you first apply the translation and then $L$ or the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the notation of the book? I didn't understand exactly what $Lf$ means

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: $Lf$ denotes the result of applying the operator $L$ to the function $f$. For instance, if $L$ is the differentiation operator, $L=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$, then $Lf=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$. (I chose that example because the differentiation operator commutes with translations.)

Comment: What is the meaning of $f\circ T$ then?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: That depends on which translation or rotation $T$ stands for. For instance, if $T$ stands for a translation by $a$ in one dimension, then $(f\circ T)(x)=f(x+a)$. Beware that there are two different conventions for such transformations; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation). I can't tell from the snippet you included which convention that book uses.